# How can I group agents to enter a process?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I am simulating a bakery process. My agent is bread carts. The bread carts must go through fermentation tunnels, where it is expected to group 6 carts to enter the tunnel. Now, for the last batch of carts, it's usually less than 6, so the number of carts at that time is entered. How can I program? What blocks can help me simulate this situation?

What blocks can help me simulate this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The `Batch` block is designed for this.

To account for the last batch, you could change the required batch size when it is time, using `set_batchSize(1)`

More details here: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/batch.html#batch